# Storybook 5.2 (CSF) - How to add react-router-dom Link - "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, storybook

I am getting an error in my story, because my component is using `<Link to="/" />`. As far as I can understand the link will have no context in a story so I need to add a decorator, however most articles that describe this are not using the Component Story Format (CSF).

**Any ideas how to do this globally or straight into the story?**

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

[image]

This is my stories file.

```
// ./stories.tsx.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { LinkComponent } from '.'
import { StoryRouter } from 'storybook-react-router'

export default {
  title: 'LinkComponent'
}

export const base = () => {
  return <LinkComponent/>
}
```

This is my component:

```
// ./LinkComponent.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const LinkComponent = () => {
  return (
    <section className="links">
       <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </section>
  )
}
```

I have tried `addDecorator(StoryRouter());` globally in the storybook config as many people suggest, but it breaks the code.

```
// /.storybook/config.ts
import StoryRouter from 'storybook-react-router';

addDecorator(StoryRouter());
configure(require.context('../src', true, /stories\.tsx$/), module)
```

Answer (score 3):

Total face-palm moment!!

There is no reason to add a decorator. You can simply import and wrap your component in `<MemoryRouter/>` to simulate the context of the link.

```
// ./stories.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { LinkComponent } from '.'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export default {
  title: 'LinkComponent'
}

export const base = () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <LinkComponent/>
    </MemoryRouter>
}
```

And... Bob's your uncle(I dont have an uncle called Bob!?!)!

Comment: One gotcha here, when doing it this way the code view in Storybook will ouput the `MemoryRouter` code as well. Not critical, but if you want to keep the code output in Storybook clean with just what's needed for that specific component, decorators are the way to go.